# Combo box DisplayMember of a value

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm pretty new to WPF and searched several sites and pages, but didn't really found my problem:

I fill my Combobox with values and different displaymembers

C#:

```
comboRaum.DataContext = dtLoad.DefaultView;
        comboRaum.DisplayMemberPath = dtLoad.Columns["Name"].ToString();
        comboRaum.SelectedValuePath = dtLoad.Columns["ID_Room"].ToString();
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboRaum" Margin="5" Height="26" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Now I read the ID_Room from ANOTHER table with an SQLDataReader. The reader works fine, all other things are displayed right.

```
sqlreaderDetails["ID_Room"].ToString();
```

How do I get my Combobox to set the item with the same value as the selected item? It jumps always to the first entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Added

```
SelectedValuePath="Content"
```

To my XAML Combobox properties. Now I can set the SelectedItem with SelectedValue = ID at runtime.